# How do I install and run Pyright from the CLI instead of using VS Code?

Tags: python, python-typing, pyright

I would like to begin using [Pyright](https://github.com/Microsoft/pyright) with my team's projects. I have installed [the Visual Studio Code plugin](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-pyright.pyright), and can see the type errors in my editor as I work. But I would like to be able to run it automatically as part of our test suite, including on our CI server, and a VS Code plugin can't do that. I need to install and use it as a standalone command-line tool.

Pyright's documentation said that it has a command-line interface, but the only installation and build instructions were for the Visual Studio Code extension, and installing that didn't add a `pyright` executable:

```
$ pyright
-bash: pyright: command not found
```

How can I install and run Pyright on my Python project from the command-line?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Even though it's a tool for Python programmers, Pyright is implemented in TypeScript running on Node, and [the documentation tells us](https://github.com/Microsoft/pyright#installation) that it can be installed using one of the package managers for that ecosystem, such as [NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm) or [Yarn](https://yarnpkg.com/en/). If you want to install it for use anywhere in the system (not just from within a particular Node project), you'll want a `global` installation.

```
npm install --global pyright
```

*or*

```
yarn global add pyright
```

This will add the `pyright` command-line interface.

```
$ pyright
Usage: pyright [options] file...
```

You can run this against your files by just specifying them on the command-line, but for a project you may want to [create a `pyrightconfig.json` file](https://github.com/Microsoft/pyright/blob/master/docs/configuration.md) identifying the files to be type-checked, and the Python interpreters, libraries, and type definitions that it should use. Some of these options [can also be passed as command-line arguments](https://github.com/Microsoft/pyright/blob/master/docs/command-line.md), but not all of them.

Comment: Can you post your `pyrightconfig.json` along with the answer?

Comment: ...why would they implement a python linting tool using typescript

Comment: Well, I would definitely prefer having a Python linter written in C++ or Rust; for large projects it is much faster and can multithread more easily. Now typescript... the only reason I can think of is that it does not need a Python environment to run it (e.g. a linter running on a web-based client like web VS code(?)